# Javascript is working only first time in the loop

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have this foreach loop inside laravel blade. which is only producing one time and making the giving that specific CSS onclick and on the second click removing those CSS styles. But on the rest of the populated data, it applies CSS but does not remove.

```
@foreach($campaigns as $campaign)

        <div id="opac" class="row d-flex border-bottom border-secondary mt-4" style="color:white">
            <div class="col-5 col-md-2 mb-4">

                <div class="d-flex">
                    <div class="ml-2">
                        
                        <span id="artist_name" class="text-muted" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"">{{$campaign->artist_name}}</span> <br>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    @endforeach
```

Javascript

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#opac").click(function() {
            //Check to see if background color is set or if it's set to white.
            if (this.style.background == "") {
                $(this).css('background', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)');
                $(this).css('padding-top', '15px');
            } else {
                $(this).css('background', '');
                $(this).css('padding-top', '15px');
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: In HTML, `id`s are supposed to be unique in the DOM - since `#opac` is present every loop iteration, you have invalid HTML - maybe try changing it to classes? (i.e. `.opac`)

Comment: Yes I tried that. it is same. it selects other but does not deselect them when I try to select another one

Comment: Please also ensure that the JS is at the bottom of the page (or at least **after** the templates are rendered)

Comment: Yes it is at the bottom of the page

Comment: if you want to select and deselect then wouldn't toggle be a better option

Answer (score 0):

Your template has a few issues

1. IDs are supposed to be unique, if you have more than one `#opac` then you should really use a class (i.e. `.opac`)
2. Your `<span>` tag (in the artist name, template) has an extra double-quote at the end (need to remove it
3. There is no closing tab for the first `<div>` so your template is not valid HTML

Once you fix these issues, you are likely to get something working.

Mind you you are changing the padding at top on click (not sure why) and your background is white while also starting with white text color (on first `div` you have declared: `style="color:white"`) basically giving you white on white.

One more thing, instead of changing attributes, you can just toggle classes added/removed from an element

See demo below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".opac").click(function() {
    //Check to see if background color is set or if it's set to white.
    this.classList.toggle('gray');
    
    console.log(this.style.background);
    $(this).css('padding-top', '15px');
  });
});
```

```css
.white{
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

.gray{
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="opac row d-flex border-bottom border-secondary mt-4" style="color: red">
  <div class="col-5 col-md-2 mb-4">

    <div class="d-flex">
      <div class="ml-2">

        <span id="artist_name" class="text-muted" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
        artist name
        </span>
        <br/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="opac row d-flex border-bottom border-secondary mt-4" style="color:red">
  <div class="col-5 col-md-2 mb-4">

    <div class="d-flex">
      <div class="ml-2">

        <span id="artist_name" class="text-muted" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
        artist name 2
        </span>
        <br/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row opac d-flex border-bottom border-secondary mt-4" style="color:red">
  <div class="col-5 col-md-2 mb-4">

    <div class="d-flex">
      <div class="ml-2">

        <span id="artist_name" class="text-muted" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
        artist name3
        </span>
        <br/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```